# Does Akazawa die in Another?

Tags: another

In the anime, Akazawa was last shown with several shards of glass embedded in her, and the building was burning down. In the manga, they showed a scene of three classmates from 9th grade class 3 visiting her in the hospital, but she was recovered only weeks later, but they skipped this in the anime.

Did they stray from the manga and kill her off?